# COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040305

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

We have an applicaton which exports the content from exchange server(using outlook) to the XML, we used Redemption for this purpose and everything seems to be fine. But currently we are encountering a COMException as follow:

**COMException: Error in IMAPISession::OpenEntry: MAPI_E_TOO_BIG
at Redemption.RDOMailClass.get_Subject()**

What might be the cause for this kind of excetpion?
Is this a Redemption Related or Outlook Related Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indication that you open too many objects without releasing them.

Avoid multiple dot notation and release all Redemption objects as soon as you are done with them using Marshal.ReleaseComObject().

Comment: we are using following code to release the COM Object.

private static void NAR(object o)
        {
            try
            {
                if (o != null)
                {
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o);
                }
            }
            catch { }
            //finally
            //{
            //    o = null;
            //}
        }

Do we need to use Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o); instead of Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o); ?
Is this causing the Issue?

Comment: And what is the rest of your code? Are you sure you do not create implicit objects by using multiple dot notation, foreach loops, etc.?